# Displaying categories and subcategories in php having different tables

Tags: php

Just wanted to ask if there is an other way of PHP coding for displaying my subcategories and subsubcategries than mine.

My tables:

> ```
> Categories
> -------------------------
> cat_ID | cat_name
> ------------------
> 4      | Baby & Kids
> 5      | Bicycles
> 6      | Boats
> 7      | Books & Comics
> ....
> 13     | Clothes & Accessories
> ....
> 35     | Sport & Fitness
> 36     | Study
> ....
> 38     | Toys & Games
> ....
>
>
> Subcategories
> -------------------------
> subcat_ID | cat_ID | extra_cat_ID | subcat_name
> ------------------------------------------------
> ....
> 15        | 4      | 13           | Baby clothes
> 16        | 4      | 0            | Baby products
> 17        | 4      | 13           | Kids clothes
> 18        | 4      | 38           | Toys
> 19        | 5      | 0            | Bycicles
> 20        | 5      | 0            | Bycicle gear & Accessories
> 21        | 6      | 0            | Boat parts
> 22        | 6      | 0            | Other Boats
> 23        | 6      | 0            | Power Boats
> 24        | 6      | 0            | Sailboats
> 25        | 6      | 35           | Windsurf & Surfing
> 26        | 7      | 0            | Antiquarian
> 27        | 7      | 0            | Books
> 28        | 7      | 38           | Childrens books
> 29        | 7      | 0            | Comics
> 30        | 7      | 0            | Magazines & Newspapers
> 31        | 7      | 36           | Study & Training
>
>
>
> Subsubcategories
> -------------------------
> subsubcat_ID | subcat_ID | subsubcat_name
> -----------------------------------------
> ...
> 470          | 15        | Baptism outfits
> 471          | 15        | Bibs
> 472          | 15        | Body warmers
> 473          | 15        | Bodysuits
> ....
> 496          | 16        | Baby bath
> 497          | 16        | Baby books
> 498          | 16        | Baby inserts
> 499          | 16        | Baby monitors
> ....
> 548          | 17        | Belts
> 549          | 17        | Blouses & Shirts
> 550          | 17        | Body warmer
> 551          | 17        | Boots
> ....
> ....
> 740          | 26        | Music
> 741          | 26        | Navy
> 742          | 26        | Novel
> 743          | 26        | Photography
> ....
> ....
> 867          | 30        | Animals
> 868          | 30        | Arts and Culture
> 869          | 30        | Branch
> 870          | 30        | Cars
> 870          | 30        | Computers
> ....
> ....
> etc.
> ```

I know it's just super basic HTML, but what I want to do is this:

> ```
> subcat_name 1
>
> subsubcatname 1
> subsubcatname 2
> subsubcatname 3
> subsubcatname 4
> subsubcatname 5
> subsubcatname 6
> subsubcatname 7
>
> subcat_name 2
>
> subsubcatname 8
> subsubcatname 9
> subsubcatname 10
> subsubcatname 11
> subsubcatname 12
>
> subcat_name 3
>
> subsubcatname 13
> subsubcatname 14
> subsubcatname 15
> subsubcatname 16
> subsubcatname 17
> subsubcatname 18
>
> etc ...
> ```

My code I use right now:

```
$result=mysqli_query($connect,"SELECT subcategories.subcat_name, subsubcategories.subsubcat_name, subcategories.subcat_ID FROM subcategories INNER JOIN subsubcategories ON subcategories.subcat_ID=subsubcategories.subcat_ID WHERE subcategories.cat_ID = $cat_ID OR subcategories.extra_cat_ID = $cat_ID ORDER BY subcategories.subcat_name, subsubcategories.subsubcat_name ASC");
$lastcat = 0;
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
    if($lastcat != $row['subcat_ID']){
        $lastcat = $row['subcat_ID'];
        echo "<br>"; 
        echo $row['subcat_name'];
        echo "<br>";
        echo "<br>";
        }
    echo $row['subsubcat_name'];
    echo "<br>";
    }
```

My code is working fine but what I want to know is if there is a better or safer way of handling it in PHP? Or am I doing it the right way?

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! The first part of your question is on-topic (and a good question), but the second part "What am I doing wrong?" is not on-topic here. (Hint if I remember my PHP correctly: Find out what mysqli_stmt_execute returns, and what parameter mysqli_fetch_array requires).

Comment: Ok I'll delete last part and ask at Stackoverfloaw. Wasn't aware it was seperated that strictly. Good to know. Thank you. :)

Comment: @  Simon André Forsberg Thanks for the hint! ;)

Comment: I've removed the updated code as it should be posted as a new follow-up question for further review.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, let's see:

- You are vulnerable to **[SQL injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection)**: By including variables directly in the query, you are making yourself vulnerable to SQL injection attacks. Use **[prepared statements](http://www.php.net//manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php)**. Further reading: **[How can I prevent SQL Injection in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)**
- Don't use `<br>` for vertical spacing control. You should use proper semantic elements, for example:

  ```
  <ul>
      <li>Subcat 1
          <ul>
              <li>Subsubcat 1</li>
              <li>Subsubcat 2</li>
              <li>Subsubcat 3</li>
          </ul>
      </li>
  </ul>
  ```

Aside from that, LGTM. Good job! :)

---

Example for prepared statements:

```
$stmt = mysqli_prepare($connect, "SELECT subcategories.subcat_name, subsubcategories.subsubcat_name, subcategories.subcat_ID FROM subcategories INNER JOIN subsubcategories ON subcategories.subcat_ID=subsubcategories.subcat_ID WHERE subcategories.cat_ID = ? OR subcategories.extra_cat_ID = ? ORDER BY subcategories.subcat_name, subsubcategories.subsubcat_name ASC");
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "ii", $cat_ID, $cat_ID);
mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
```

Comment: Thank you Madara. Could you show me how this code looks like implemented in mine? Can't figure out how these prepared statements work. Thanks!

Comment: Added example..

Comment: @ Madara Uchiha Thanks Madara. I tried to implement this but it seems I'm doing something wrong. I asked for help [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24135824/displaying-categories-and-subcategories-in-php-having-different-tables-prepare) because this is the codereview site.

Comment: @ Madara Uchiha I think I found how to implement this. At least it works. Can you dubbelcheck for me please? Also gonna work on the html list elements now. Thanks for you advice!