# Displaying subcategories of subcategories

Tags: php, mysqli, sql-injection, join

I wanted to know if this code is safe against SQL injection or not?
Also do I need to `mysqli_close` if I already did the `mysqli_stmt_close`?  Other suggestions are always welcome.

```
if ($stmt = mysqli_prepare($connect, "SELECT subcategories.subcat_name, subsubcategories.subsubcat_name, subcategories.subcat_ID FROM subcategories INNER JOIN subsubcategories ON subcategories.subcat_ID=subsubcategories.subcat_ID WHERE subcategories.cat_ID = ? OR subcategories.extra_cat_ID = ? ORDER BY subcategories.subcat_name, subsubcategories.subsubcat_name ASC")){
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "ii", $cat_ID, $cat_ID);
mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
mysqli_stmt_bind_result($stmt, $subcat_name, $subsubcat_name, $subcat_ID);
$lastcat = 0;
while (mysqli_stmt_fetch($stmt)){
    if($lastcat != $subcat_ID){
        $lastcat = $subcat_ID;
        echo "<br>"; 
        echo $subcat_name;
        echo "<br>";
        echo "<br>";
        }

    echo $subsubcat_name;
    echo "<br>";
    }
}
mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
mysqli_close($connect);
```

Comment: This seems like a practice project, but as soon as your projects get larger, you're going to want to separate the database and the presentation of the application. That would mean moving the `echo "<br>";`s away from the database connecting code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### SQL Injection

Yes, your code is **safe** against SQL Injection. Make sure to use prepared statements when fetching things from the database as well, even in internal application services without user input.

### Others

Well, I'm guessing this is a subset of the code in [Displaying categories and subcategories in php having different tables](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/53865/displaying-categories-and-subcategories-in-php-having-different-tables), so my review there still stands.